# Splitting Child forest from Main forest will impact SharePoint 2013 or 2016 On-premises environment?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, user-profile, user-profile-service

We have a scenario where existing child Forest users want to separate from the Main forest and have their own dedicated AD. The plan is to migrate all the objects from the main DC/DN to a dedicated domain/AD. Because these two companies have split.

The issue is that we have SharePoint 2013 and SharePoint 2016 on-premises environment. Because the DN will change and a dedicated AD, Do I need to re-configure User Profile sync?

If yes, will it impact all the permissions and workflows?

How can we make sure the account will still work as it is even after the split from main Forest?

**Note**: We will still carry SID history. Only Child Forest users have access to these two environments